# how to show error msg in literal if no record found in database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how to show error msg in literal if no record found in database according to the text entered in textbox1 and textbox2 else if show record in gridview if the text entered in textbox1 and textbox2 will be found in database ...

how to do this ....using vb.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something that we can answer directly, you will need to determine exactly how you want to execute the query as that will determine the exact implementation of how you want to do this.

- SqlDataReader - If this you can use the "HasRows()" property to see if there are results
- DataSet/DataTable - If this you can look at the row count for the table that you loaded
- Others - Will vary depending on what you are doing.

Also, for the SQL querying are you going against a stored procedure?  Looking to build out the SQL statement?